# Kill a Command Handler script in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fs

I am developing a bot for discord using discord.js but I was not good at coding. What I want to do is to get a command to start a process to ask and then take user input. So the bot will ask something and it would listen to the user messages. But I also want a command to stop this asking process. Is there any way to kill the command handler for this specific command but not main.js? My main.js and The command handler I used:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const fs = require('fs')
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection()

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
 
    bot.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

bot.on('message', message =>{
    if(command === 'ask'){
        bot.commands.get('ask').execute(message,args, bot)
    }
}
```

Command Handler:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ask',
    execute(message, args, bot){
         bot.on('message', msg =>{
             if(msg.content.toLowerCase() == "endask"){
                // So is there anyway here to only kill this command handler
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first, you should probably try to learn a little more about command handlers, as you seem to be putting an event inside of one, and the way you would "end" it would be using "return" and it will stop your command.